# How to reply mail that contains attachment?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have created email client that displays messages and when as I click reply that mail should be replied with attachment, but my `enctype='multipart/form-data'>` doesn't attcepts `bodypart.getContent()` or any other method.
please help me in solving this problem soon, as I have to subject my project.

**composereplymail.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="user.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.activation.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
    String sendmessage=(String)request.getAttribute("sendmessage");
    if(sendmessage==null)
    {
        sendmessage="";
    }

    if (session == null) {
        response.sendError(404, "Session expired");
        return;
    }
    userinfo info = (userinfo)session.getAttribute("userinfo");

    Session sessio = info.getSession();
    Store store = sessio.getStore("imap");
      store.connect(info.getHostname(),info.getusername(),info.getpassword());
    Folder folder = store.getFolder(info.getUrl()); 
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Integer messageno=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("messageno"));
    Message[] message = folder.getMessages();
    String subject=message[messageno].getSubject();


%>



<html><head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleforcomposemail.css" />
</head>
  <body>
<center>
<form action='sendmail' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <table>
       <tr bgcolor='#800517'>
        <td colspan='2'><b><h3><center>Compose Your Mail Here</center></h3></b></td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="15" bgcolor='#CFECEC'>
        <td><b>From :</td>
        <td><label for="login"><%= info.getsendfrom() %></label></td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="15" bgcolor='#CFECEC'>
        <td><b>TO :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='sendto' class='Large' value='<%= message[messageno].getFrom()[0]  %>' /></b>separate addresses with commas</td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="15" bgcolor='#CFECEC'>
        <td><b  >CC :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='cc' class='Large' /></b></td>
       </tr>
       <tr height="15" bgcolor='#CFECEC'>
        <td><b>Subject :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='subject' class='Large' value='Re : <%=subject%>' /></td>
       </tr>


<%

MimeMessage reply = (MimeMessage) message[messageno].reply(false);

Multipart multipart=(Multipart)message[messageno].getContent();

for(int i=0;i<multipart.getCount();i++)
{
    BodyPart bodypart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

    String disposition = bodypart.getDisposition();

    if(disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT)))
    {

        //saveFile(bodypart.getFileName(),bodypart.getInputStream());


    String filename=bodypart.getFileName();

    String FilePath="C:\\nikki\\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\\webapps\\Email\\download\\"+filename;
    String FileDownloadPath="\\Email\\download\\"+filename;
    DataHandler dh = bodypart.getDataHandler();
    %>

       <tr height="15" bgcolor='#CFECEC'>

        <td><b>Attachment :</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="attachment" value="<%=bodypart.getContent()%>"/><a href="<%=FileDownloadPath%>"><%=filename%></a></td>//**what method should i pass over here to get that file sent with multipart/form-data**
       </tr>
    <%}else{%>

       <tr bgcolor='#CFECEC'>
        <td colspan='2'><textarea id="textAreaa" rows='32' cols='135' name='data'><%=bodypart.getContent()%></textarea></td>
       </tr>
    <%}}%>
       <tr height="15" bgcolor='#CFECEC'>
        <td colspan='2'><input type='submit' class='button' name='Submit' value='Submit'/>
                <input type='submit' class='button' name='Draft' value='Save As Draft'/>
                <input type='reset' class='button' value='Reset' name='Reset'/>
                <input type='reset' class='button' value='Discard' name='Reset'/>
        </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
  </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do...

Normally, when replying to a message, you *don't* want the reply to include all the attachments of the original message.

And in any event, you definitely don't want to send the attachment to the browser client only so it can send it back to you as an attachment.  Perhaps what you really want is to allow the user to select a file that will be attached to the reply?

The JavaMail download bundle includes several demo programs, one servlet based and one JSP based, have you looked at them?

Comment: thanks for reply, in my program, when user compose a mail he/she can only send one attachment, when the recipients display a message and recipients click on reply button than i want that the attached attachment as a part should again go back to sendmail.java from composereplymail.jsp without giving facility of file the file tag.

Comment: i also need to forward mail so similarly that mail must also be forwarded so similar coding but problem is above mentioned....please help

Comment: Forwarding is different than replying, in that case you *do* want the attachments.  Did you look at the examples I pointed you to?  See also the JavaMail FAQ entry that talks about forwarding messages.